# Need to deploy to staging

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-cli

Hi I am trying to deploy to staging only when the code is pushed to staging and deploy to master only when the code is pushed to master Please help me accomplish this, here is the groovy script.

```
node{
  currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"

  try {
    stage('Pull-msater') {
      // pulling master from the repo
      git 'https://github.com/raj1rana/mongoDB-docker.git'
    }

    stage('pull-staging'){
      //pulling staging from the repo
      git branch: 'staging', url: 'https://github.com/raj1rana/mongoDB-docker.git'
    }

    stage('deploy-staging') {
      //deploy to staging server
      sh 'rsync -avz  -e ssh --exclude .git /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline-test/  ubuntu@13.232.107.33:/home/ubuntu/Docker-files/'
    }

    stage('deploy-production'){
      //deploy to production server
      sh 'rsync -avz -e ssh  --exclude .git  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline-test/  ubuntu@13.232.107.33:/home/ubuntu/master'
    }

    stage('mail fail/sucess'){
      mail body: 'project build successful',
      from: 'xxxx@yyyyy.com',
      replyTo: 'xxxx@yyyy.com',
      subject: 'project build successful',
      to: 'yyyyy@yyyy.com'
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"

    mail body: "project build error is here: ${env.BUILD_URL}" ,
    from: 'xxxx@yyyy.com',
    replyTo: 'yyyy@yyyy.com',
    subject: 'project build failed',
    to: 'zzzz@yyyyy.com'

    throw err
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make use of the `env.BRANCH_NAME` to achieve it.

```
if(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
  // some build steps
} else  {
  // some build steps
}
```

Comment: HI i did that also but the issue is that i use webhook to auto-deploy the code from git to Jenkins that is not working with the script Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

in your pipeline you are doing two times (master and staging)git checkout in same directory i.e. workspace directory. So final result will be checkout of staging directory.

You can simplify the build process by creating two jobs one is for production and one is for staging, don't mix both in one job.

Below example is for staging:

```
node{
  currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"

  try {

    stage('pull-staging'){
      //pulling staging from the repo
      git branch: 'staging', url: 'https://github.com/raj1rana/mongoDB-docker.git'
    }

    stage('deploy-staging') {
      //deploy to staging server
      sh 'rsync -avz  -e ssh --exclude .git /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline-test/  ubuntu@13.232.107.33:/home/ubuntu/Docker-files/'
    }

    stage('mail fail/sucess'){
      mail body: 'project build successful',
      from: 'xxxx@yyyyy.com',
      replyTo: 'xxxx@yyyy.com',
      subject: 'project build successful',
      to: 'yyyyy@yyyy.com'
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"

    mail body: "project build error is here: ${env.BUILD_URL}" ,
    from: 'xxxx@yyyy.com',
    replyTo: 'yyyy@yyyy.com',
    subject: 'project build failed',
    to: 'zzzz@yyyyy.com'

    throw err
  }
}
```

Below example is for production:

```
node{
  currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"

  try {
    stage('Pull-msater') {
      // pulling master from the repo
      git 'https://github.com/raj1rana/mongoDB-docker.git'
    }

    stage('deploy-production'){
      //deploy to production server
      sh 'rsync -avz -e ssh  --exclude .git  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline-test/  ubuntu@13.232.107.33:/home/ubuntu/master'
    }

    stage('mail fail/sucess'){
      mail body: 'project build successful',
      from: 'xxxx@yyyyy.com',
      replyTo: 'xxxx@yyyy.com',
      subject: 'project build successful',
      to: 'yyyyy@yyyy.com'
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"

    mail body: "project build error is here: ${env.BUILD_URL}" ,
    from: 'xxxx@yyyy.com',
    replyTo: 'yyyy@yyyy.com',
    subject: 'project build failed',
    to: 'zzzz@yyyyy.com'

    throw err
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i have tried this also but there are two issues 1st that the mail is not working second is that the CI from my gitea server is not working